# cakephp 3 belongstomany help pls

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to this framework, and in the english language too (haha).

But here is my problem: 
I do some code using the `belongsto` of the cake. I think I did everything right. But when I click *submit*, he only register the information of the table and dont do the association.

**My tables:**

```
Planos
Servidores
Servidores_Planos
```

**My code:**

table/PlanosTable.php

```
$this->belongsToMany('Servidores', [
    'class' => 'servidores',
    'joinTable' => 'servidores_planos',
    'foreignKey' => 'planos_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'servidores_id'
]);
```

table/ServidoresTable.php

```
 $this->belongsToMany('Planos', [
    'joinTable' => 'servidores_planos',
    'foreignKey' => 'servidores_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'planos_id'
 ]);
```

I dont think it is necessary to show the controller code, because the add page from `planos` receive the `servidores`.

And this is my input in add page.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('servidores.id',array('type'=>'select','multiple','label'=>false,'id'=>'selectServidor', 'class'=>'form-group', 'name' => 'servidores[]', 'options'=> $servidores,'style' => 'width:430px;height:180px;')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify your view slightly. Try this :

```
   echo $this->Form->input('servidores._ids', [
      'type'     => 'select',
      'multiple' => true,
      'label'    => false,
      'id'       => 'selectServidor', 
      'class'    => 'form-group', 
      //'name'   => 'servidores[]', /* This name field is generated automatically */
      'options'  =>  $servidores,
      'style'    => 'width:430px;height:180px;'
   ]);
```

This should solve your issue. In your controller, make sure you're following the convention and passing the appropriate parameters for saving associated data.

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD